# Pandas multiple filter str.contains or not contains

Tags: python, pandas

I need to build multiple filter on 2 columns
structure of table is 7 columns , but first 'query' and last 'template' is filtering

I done it beforeand it worked but now (1 year later) i cant figure out whats wrong.

```
for item in glob.glob('D:\\path\\*.change'):
    table = pd.read_csv(item, sep='\t', index_col=None)
#FILTERING
    filtered_table = table[
        (table['query'].str.contains("egg*", regex=True)==False) &
        (table['query'].str.contains(".*phospho*", regex=True)==False) &
        (table['query'].str.contains("vipe", regex=True)==False) &
        (table['template'].str.contains("ABC1")) |
        (table['template'].str.contains("bender")) ]
```

Expected result is the table  without rows containing strings - egg*, .*phospho*, vipe in column 'query' AND rows in column 'template' which contain 'ABC1' or 'bender'.

Comment: based on the description in your question should that final `|` be an `&`? Otherwise it's doing an OR comparison

Comment: sorry its no and but or !

Comment: I think you need a pair of brackets around your last 2 masks, try that out and I'll write it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer for problem:

```
for item in glob.glob('D:\\path\\*.change'):
    table = pd.read_csv(item, sep='\t', index_col=None)
#FILTERING
    query_table = table[
        (table['query'].str.contains("egg*", regex=True)==False) &
        (table['query'].str.contains(".*phospho*", regex=True)==False) &
        (table['query'].str.contains("vipe", regex=True)==False)  ]

  filtered_table = query_table[
        (query_table['template'].str.contains("ABC1")) |
        (query_table['template'].str.contains("bender")) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's something with the missing brackets in your condition.

Try this:

```
table[(
       # AND condition
       table['query'].str.contains("egg*", regex=True)==False &
       table['query'].str.contains(".*phospho*", regex=True)==False &
       table['query'].str.contains("vipe", regex=True)==False &
       # OR condition
       (table['template'].str.contains("ABC1") |
        table['template'].str.contains("bender"))
      )]
```

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().